# Number of points needed to determine a sparse univariate polynomial over a large prime field with known support

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, interpolation, cryptography

Consider a sparse polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$, of maximum degree $k$, with a known support of $t$ terms. That is, we know a set $I \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $\#I = t$ and $f(x) = \sum_{i \in I} {a_i x^i}$. Some of the $a_i$ may be zero. $p$ is much larger than $t$ or $k$.

What is the size of a minimal set $U$ of points in $\mathbb{F}_p$ such that knowing $f(u)$ for each $u \in U$ determines $f$?

(Clarification: I'm looking for how to choose a minimal set, as well as its size.)

Intuitively it should be $t$ — but is that right, are there any side-conditions, and how do I prove it? Also, if it matters which points I choose to minimize $\#U$, how should I choose them?

The dense case is proven [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Uniqueness_of_the_interpolating_polynomial).

Similar, but not identical question: [Interpolating $t$-sparse polynomial with $t+1$ evaluations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2405981/interpolating-t-sparse-polynomial-with-t1-evaluations). It's not identical because the support is known, and because in this context I don't need to actually do the interpolation, only to prove that there is a unique solution.

A somewhat related paper is [What Can (and Can't) we Do with Sparse Polynomials](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.08289.pdf), which references [On the bit-complexity of sparse polynomial and series multiplication](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00476223/document).

(If you're curious, this problem arises in the context of optimizing Toom-Cook-style multiplication of sparse elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^{12}}$ obtained from line functions, during computation of cryptographic pairings.)

Comment: Thanks for correcting the $\prod$ vs $\sum$ typo, Arthur B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being able to determine $f$ boils down to whether or not the submatrix of the Vandermonde matrix with indices in $I$ is invertible or not. This is not always true but we can construct examples where it is:

Consider $p=8191$, $k = 13$, $I = \{0, 13\}$ and $U = \{1_{p}, 2_{p}\}$.

Polynomials $1_p + x^{13}$ and $2_p x^{13}$ both take values $\{2_{p}, 2_{p}\}$ on $U$.

Whenever you can have points in $U$ related by a $i$th root of unity with $i$ in $I$ you can construct a singular Vandermonde matrix.

Are you looking for the number of points you need such that whenever $U$ has that many points you can reconstruct the polynomial, or are you looking for **a** minimal set of points which lets you reconstruct any polynomial?

In which case, consider $g \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and $U = \{x_0,\ldots,x_{t-1}\} = \{1_p,g,g^2,\ldots,g^{t-1}\}$

The Vandermonde matrix becomes $V_{i,j} = (g^{j})^i = (g^{i})^j$ which is also the Vandermonde matrix for polynomials of degree $t-1$ taken at points $g^i$ for $i$ in $I$. So long as they these points take distinct values, the polynomial can be recovered.

Comment: Thankyou!

"Are you looking for the number of points you need such that whenever U has that many points you can reconstruct the polynomial, or are you looking for a minimal set of points which lets you reconstruct any polynomial?" <-- the latter

Comment: ... and [here's what I wanted to use it for](https://github.com/zcash/zcash/issues/3425#issuecomment-464496368).